# Swift Custom Xcode Project Templates

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, project-template, xcode-project

I'm trying to create Xcode project templates with swift and got bit success but facing issues to load xib file

> Error popup when xib selected in Xcode: "Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of "ViewController.xib". This may be due to a missing SDK."

anyone know how to create xib file in Xcode project template?

I have added project template at below path:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/CustomTemplate/

and created below folders..

> /Base.xctemplate
>
> /Bundle Base.xctemplate
>
> /iOS Application.xctemplate
>
> /Swift Application.xctemplate

Few queries I have for Xcode template usage:

1. I have not found any apple documentation for creating Xcode project templates, so that mean apple stoped supporting to create Xcode custom project templates?
2. Swift apps allows to have custom Xcode project templates?
3. Apple will reject app submitted which was built with custom project templates?
4. Xcode custom project templates are better way to have it in practice or not?
5. All links and reference I found are upto Xcode4.x, is that mean no support available for Xcode project templates then after?

Reference: 
http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-create-custom-project-templates-in-xcode-7

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: I found some documentation for templates...

Reference :

> http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/files/xcode4-template-doc/Xcode4-Template-Documentation.zip

> http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/tag/templateinfo-plist/

Comment: Did you able to fix that error?

Comment: nope, facing same.. still trying to solve it. do you have any ideas?

Comment: No yet, I'm still stuck there. Can not preload xib in custom template