# Edit Swift class template in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, templates, ide

There are similar questions about how to edit Xcode file templates in general:

[Swift Custom Xcode Project Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001501/swift-custom-xcode-project-templates)

[Change templates in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720/change-templates-in-xcode)

But there is no template file for swift when you create new Swift class via `File > New > File... > Cocoa Touch Class > choose swift language`. Swift template exists for `File > New > File... > Swift file` only and it doesn't create "class description".

I need to create a new template (or edit this one) which is similar to this one but:

- with no top comment lines ("created by ...")
- with optional `NSObject` subclassing

In other words I need to create files with the following code:

```
import Foundation

class SomeVaryingClass {
}
```

How to make such template?

Comment: What is a "class description"? Can you show how you'd use the template?

Comment: @Sweeper added an example. The main problem is I don't know where is an appropriate template